# Aplicaciones Web Sin Plantillas Predefinidas

Tags: asp.net-core, vscode, c#-8.0

Visual Studio Code 1.47 | .NET Core 3.1

Hola a todos

Cuando, al utilizar Visual Studio Code, se aplica el comando siguiente:

**dotnet new webapp**

se genera una estructura básica de un nuevo Proyecto Web, en la cual se tiene la **Carpeta www**, en cuyo interior existen **SubCarpetas** como **CSS** y **lib** (y dentro de ésta, la **SubCarpeta bootstrap**)  las cuales tienen un conjunto de **archivos** ya editados **que "imponen" estilos predefinidos al Proyecto**.

Si bien es cierto el propósito es loable, existen ocasiones en las que es necesario generar un Proyecto limpio, libre de estas plantillas.

Se puede pensar en una solución simple como la de eliminar dichas Carpetas y sus Archivos, generar los propios y modificar las configuraciones iniciales, pero puede resultar tedioso y no práctico.

**¿Se puede generar una Aplicación Web con el comando dotnet que excluya las Carpetas y Archivos mencionados?**

Desde ya Muchísimas Gracias

Comment: 4 cosas: 1. Bienvenido/a a SOes, 2. Recuerda visitar el tour: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour 3. Mira cómo preguntar aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (sí, es necesario, para que obtengas buenas y mejores respuestas). 4. Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos :D

Answer (score 1):

Sí se puede, el comando a utilizar es el siguiente:

```
dotnet new web
```

Con este comando tienes un proyecto vacío de ASP.NET Core.

Referencia:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new

Comment: Gracias fredyfx, a veces uno se obnubila y no ve las herramientas que están a la vista

Comment: @Skar.2007 Un gusto colaborar :D Si la respuesta te fue de utilidad, márcala como aceptada haciendo click en el check verde del costado donde solo el que ha preguntado puede hacerlo. Todavía no has visto el tour, es importante que lo hagas, te informas mejor y ello aumenta la calidad de interacción en el sitio, también ganas tu primera medalla :D